# Replace double line breaks except when tags

Tags: php, regex-negation

I have some db content as a variable and I want to turn double line breaks into `<p>...</p>`

For single line breaks I want to add `<br />`

I can do this using:

```
$content = nl2br($content, false);
$content = '<p>' . preg_replace('#(<br>[\r\n\s]+){2}#', '</p><p>', $content) . '</p>';
```

However, I need to exclude paragraphs that have h2, h3, h4, ul and are inside ul tags. But I need to still add p tags around other HTML tags such as `<strong>`  `<blockquote>` `<img>` `<i> <em>` and `<caption>` etc

An example text would be:

```
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h2>

Vivamus vel tempor turpis, <strong>non rutrum quam</strong>. Suspendisse ac rhoncus felis, eget porta lectus. 

Nam vulputate sapien risus, vel vehicula mi volutpat sed. 

<ul>
<li>Sed feugiat nibh at nisl eleifend scelerisque.</li>
<li>Aliquam non maximus ipsum. Aliquam erat volutpat.</li>
</ul>

<h3>Praesent eget diam sit amet leo vehicula sagittis at quis tortor</h3>

Nunc nec sem ac nunc tincidunt aliquam ut nec dolor. Nulla facilisi.

<img alt="xxxx" src="xxx.png" class="xxxxx"/> 

<caption><i>ccccc</i></caption> 

<img alt="xxxx" src="xxx.png" class="xxxxx"/> 

<i>ccccc</i>

<strong>Nunc nec sem ac nunc tincidunt aliquam ut nec dolor. Nulla facilisi.</strong>

Vivamus vel tempor turpis, <strong>non rutrum quam</strong>. Suspendisse ac rhoncus felis, eget porta lectus.

Nunc nec
Nunc nec
Nunc nec

<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Vivamus vel tempor turpis <a href=""></a></p>&mdash; xxxxx (@xxxxxx) <a href="https://twitter.com/xxxx/status/x?ref_src=x">February 15, 2019</a></blockquote>

<script async src="" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/2pnbet/1 - something so ?

Comment: Thanks. Almost works but it gives <p><ul></p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest NOT using the `nl2br()` function -- you're going to inject `<br>` tags all over the place in places where you don't want them.

Instead, I would suggest that you perform your regex off the line breaks directly, ignoring lines already surrounded with tags, like so:

`(?i)^(?!((<\/|<)(h[1-6]|ul|li|script|blockquote)(\s.+)*>))(.+)(?!(<(\/\3)>))$`

If you want to exclude more tags, put them in the `(h[1-6]|ul|li|script|blockquote)` group.

**Let's break it down:**

- `(?i)` makes all following matches case insensitive
- `^` asserts the position at the start of the line
- `?!()` grouping is a negative lookahead
- `(<\/|<)` means we match both an opening or closing tag
- `h[1-6]` matches h1, h2, h3, etc.
- `(\s.+)*>` matches extra junk inside an opening tag, e.g., `<script xyz>`
- `(.+)` is what we want to wrap paragraph tags around
- The `\3` in `<(\/\3)>` matches the original tag we matched with, for the closing tag

Notice that `(.+)` in the above regex is group 5, which is what you want to *surround* with `<p>` tags. You can reference group one using the `$5` tag in your `preg_replace()`, which allows you to wrap both an opening and closing `<p>` tag around that group.

**Here is an example of it in action:** https://regex101.com/r/TQGbaq/2

**So your code could look something like this:**

```
$regex = '#(?i)^(?!((<\/|<)(h[1-6]|ul|li|script|blockquote)(\s.+)*>))(.+)(?!(<(\/\3)>))$#';
$content = preg_replace($regex, "<p>$5</p>", $content);
```

Comment: Nice! Although there are some situations where I do need to add <p>...</p> I'm updating the question...

Comment: Also, if single line break I want to have <br /> and not add p tag around it

Comment: I updated my answer. Didn't address your use-case for a single line break as that was out of scope from the original question, but this should get you 90% of the way there.

Comment: Thanks. Strange, it works on the content in the test, but doesn't when applied to the variable in the script. The \n remain unchanged, like it's not recognising them to apply regex. I tried outputting the variable just before being regex and copying that to the tester and it works there, but not in my script!

Comment: I'll run it through a php script for you next time I'm in front of a computer, I didn't test beyond the regex fiddle

Comment: Ah the code generator here changed it to $regex = '/(?i)^(?!((<\/|<)(h[1-6]|ul|li|script|blockquote)(\s.+)*>))(.+)(?!(<(\/\3)>))$/m'; which works. Now I just need to avoid adding <p></p> for extra line breaks.

Comment: ...and avoid adding <p></p> around lines that only have single line breaks!

Comment: Yeah, this is a dicey thing you're trying to do. You're probably going to have many exceptions pop up. Hope this gets you on the right path. If you find you're getting stuck on one thing in particular, you can always pose another question, too.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll ask a fresh question to change this to only apply to double line breaks

Comment: Doesn't work. If your test string on the regex101 demonstration is `<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor\n\nsit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h2>`, the output is `<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor\n\n<p>sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h2></p>` which isn't even valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the <**br**> in the list like below :

```
$content = '<p>' . preg_replace('#([\<br\>\r\n\s]{2})#', '</p><p>', $content) . '</p>';
```